# Qt C++ destructor error

Tags: c++, qt, destructor

I have a question concerning destructors of inherited classes:

I have a parent class geometry:

```
Geometry.h:
    #ifndef GEOMETRY_H
    #define GEOMETRY_H

    #include <QDialog>
    class Geometry : public QDialog
    {
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        explicit Geometry(QWidget *parent = 0);
        virtual ~Geometry() {}
    };        
    #endif // GEOMETRY_H
```

and

```
Geometry.cpp
    #include "Geometry.h"
    #include "ui_Geometry.h"

      Geometry::Geometry(QWidget *parent) :
          QDialog(parent)  {          }
```

When I change Geometry.h to

```
 virtual ~Geometry() ;
```

and add the following to Geometry.cpp

```
Geometry::~Geometry(void)
{
   // ...
}
```

I get the error "multiple definition of Geometry::~Geometry() "

**Can you tell me why I get this error? I can put code in the .cpp-File can`t I?**

Comment: How do you build your program? Are you using an IDE or just a plain text editor? Have you remembered to save the header file? Are you using the correct header file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have this, which is a complete implementation of the destructor:

```
virtual ~Geometry() {}
```

and then you add this, which is also a complete implementation of the destructor:

```
Geometry::~Geometry(void)
{
   // ...
}
```

Thus the error you're receiving.

To fix this, remove the empty braces from the one in the header file:

```
virtual ~Geometry();
```

Edit:  I see that you made the change, so you more than likely did not rebuild your entire application with the updated header.